# Is there a way to match values in Excel when an individual cell has multiple values?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: Snapshot of Excel sheet]

Above is a picture of my Excel sheet.  I have 2 columns of data that have multiple data points in them (separated by commas).  This is how my data is spit out after running an online psychology experiment.  I'm hesitant to split text to columns because some lines only have 3 values and other lines have 20+.  Essentially, I need to match values in one column to values in the second column.  For example, the first value in column G needs to match with the first value in column H.  The second value needs to match with the second value, etc.  I don't need to match up every value in both columns, however.  I only need a (defined) subset of values.

I'm not sure if this is possible to do in Excel (or any Excel add-on) without separating the values into separate columns, but any help is appreciated!

Comment: It is a bit unclear how `Stim24`  would ever match `2.6072..`

Comment: But you don't want VBA? What exactly would you want in terms of output at the end?

Answer (score 3):

I've seen this before in survey data - the output uses "packed data" where each cell contains many values.  You will need Excel 2010+ for Windows (or Excel 365) for this solution.  Otherwise, there a solution that is also Mac compatible that does not involve VBA, but it takes time to construct.  This approach should take you 10 mins to do - a lot of steps, but it is just clicking.

Let's say that these are your data in two columns in a table.

[image]

Click anywhere inside the table.  Open the Data tab and click on From Table/Range:

[image]

This will convert your data into an Excel Table and ask you if your table has headers - yes it does. Click OK.

[image]

This will open the Power Query (PQ) editor (congratulations, you are now a step closer to data scientist, so take a selfy with this screen in the back and share on social media).

[image]

You will see in the Applied Steps on the right hand side that PQ has helpfully detected the data type in a step called Changed Type. You need to undo that because it will likely think that your comma separated numbers are just one giant number. So click the X on the left side of that step.

On the right side, you can expand out Queries as shown above.  Right click on your table and select Duplicate.

[image]

> NB: This is not the most efficient way to do this, but I think this is something you just want do one time and you probably don't want to go hacking through the Advanced Editor.

So now you have two tables:

[image: 2 tables]

Rename Table1 (2) to Output in the box on the right hand side just to create some clarity.

[image]

Right Click on the Response RT column in Output and Remove it.  Click on Table1 and do the same thing to the Response column.  So now you have Table1 with only the Response RT and Output with only the Responses.  Now we will parse these into rows of cleaned data.

**Parse Table1**

First, in Table1, click on the Response RT column and in the Home tab you will see Split Column.  **1)** Click on that and choose By Delimiter.

[image]

**2)** It will default to Comma, but you need to click on Advanced options and choose the Rows radio button.

[image]

Click OK and it should turn your data into rows of separated numbers and change to the type (this time helpfully) to decimal.

[image]

Now you need to add an index. 3) Go to the Add Column tab and click on Add Index, starting from 1.

[image]

**Parse Ouput Table**

Now go back to Output and repeat steps 1), 2) and 3) for it as well.  Then you will have to take an extra step to clean up your text column.  Right-Click on the Response column and choose Transform > Trim on the data.

[image]

That will get rid of those spurious spaces.

**Merge Them Back Together**

While you still have the Output table selected, go to the Home tab and choose Merge Queries.

[image]

It will bring up this window:

[image]

Choose Table1 from the bottom dropdown. Click on Index on both tables and click OK.  You will get something like this:

[image]

Click on the button on the top right of the Table1 column and then **unselect** *Index* and *Use original column name as prefix*.

[image]

Click OK. Right click the Index column and Remove it.  You now have your answer, but you still need to bring it back to Excel.

[image]

**Putting it back in Excel**

Click on **Close and Load to** on the left hand of the Home tab. To keep things simple, just click OK.

[image]

It will put both Output and Table1 as worksheets into your workbook, (this is where I said it is not the most efficient approach - you can always delete the Table1 worksheet. Excel will complain when you do, but you can ignore it.) Output is your answer.

Congratulations, you just did an ETL (extract transform and load) operation in data analytics.  Do another selfy with the answer and share on social media.

Comment: Just another thought - when I did this last time, the Qualtrics data were presented exactly like yours and there was one XLS worksheet per question.  That meant that the simplified operation I showed above had to be repeated each time the question results in packed data - generally multi choice questions.  If that is your case, then a PowerQuery function would be a better approach. If so, ask in comments and I can send you a script that would do it.

Comment: Thank you, this definitely seems helpful but I’m not sure if it’s the answer to my problem. The way the days comes out now (and the way I need it for other analyses) is that each row of data is 1 trial/participant. Each participant has 176 rows of data (aka 176 trials). If I transform the data this way, one participant may have 12 rows of data for 1 trial (if they made 12 clicks) and another may only have 1 row. I have to be able to know what what row goes with which trial so I can match up response & RT (or multiple responses and RTs) per trial.

Comment: Ahh OK - that is what I was referring to with the Qualtrics experience.  In my case, I had to take the whole worksheet into PowerQuery, then create an index that represented each participant and then do the univot ETL shown above.  This creates a new table called a "fact" table that can be connected (in Power Pivot) back to each participant.  That is more complex, but unfortunately, it is a little worse.  You then have to use "basket analysis" to evaluate these many-to-many relationships. So, PowerQuery and PowerPivot can do this, but it is a steep learning curve.  :-(

Comment: Okay, thanks for the info!! I’ll watch some videos and see what I can do. I may go back to my original thought of text to columns and match values based on the match function (or similar) if I can’t figure it out.

Comment: If you do a lot of work with survey data, PQ is definitely worth your time to learn. In terms of yield per hour of learning, I would say it is far above VBA or DAX.  That would, at least let you normalize your data.  So, the PQ part is really not hard and trying the steps above will get you well on your way.  DAX is not that hard to start with, but when you reach into Basket Analysis, which involves many-to-many relationships or arbitrarily shaped sets, it takes time to master. Even if you do Text-To-Columns, you might end up in the same conundrum.